# Postfix evaluation segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stack

I'm getting segmentation fault in this code for postfix evaluation using stack
pls help thanks

It isnt able to take input only as per my debugging. I feel my algorithm is correct and method too but I'm missing something small somewhere or making a silly mistake I'm not able to find.
Help will be appreciated. thanks a lot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Stack {
  int data;
  Stack *next;
}*top=NULL,*temp;

void push(int item)
{
  Stack *new_node = new Stack;
  new_node->data=item;
  new_node->next=top;
  top=new_node;
}

int pop()
{
  int item;
  if (top==NULL)
    cout<<"stack underflow";

  else {
    temp=top;
    item=top->data;
    top=top->next;
    free(temp);
  }
  return item;
}

void evaluate(char postfix)
{
  int i,val;
  int A, B;
  
  ch - '0' is used for getting digit rather than ASCII code of digit */
  if (isdigit(postfix))  
    push(postfix - '0');
   
  else if (postfix == '+' || postfix == '-' || postfix == '*' || postfix == '/') 
  {
    A = pop();
    B = pop();
    switch (postfix)
    {
      case '*': val=B*A; break;
      case '/': val=B/A; break;
      case '+': val=B+A; break;
      case '-': val=B-A; break;
    }
    push(val);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  string exp;
  getline(cin,exp);
  for (i=0;i<exp.length();i++) 
    evaluate(exp[i]);
  cout<<"Value of "<<exp<<" is "<<pop();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you run your code under a debugger, where does it crash? What is the simplest input that still triggers a crash?

Comment: You also have a typo in `top=NULL`

Comment: And that typo will crash your process. Should stand out if you step through using a debugger.

Comment: The evaluate() function doesnt work @Botje

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless diagnostic. Does it crash? Produce bad values? Loop? Fill your screen with yellow penguins? Use a debugger, step through your program, see why it goes wrong in the pop function.  Your if statement always overwrites `top`.

Comment: The evaluate function isnt called. Like the char doesnt pass as parameter so it just loads and loads until crash @Botje

Comment: How did you verify this? Under a debugger? Did you add a print statement to evaluate? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: Using a debugger @Botje

Comment: That is not possible with the code you pasted.

Comment: So I changed the cin to be inside the function and remved the parameter and now it works... So thankssss a ton

Answer (score 0):

Look at the if statement inside your `pop` function:

```
  if (top=NULL)
    cout<<"stack underflow";

  else {
    temp=top;
    item=top->data;
    top=top->next;
    free(temp);
  }
```

`top=NULL` always overwrites `top` with `NULL` and then takes the else branch (because NULL is false), where `top->data` will dereference the freshly-assigned null pointer.

Even an input as simple as `5` will trigger this problem, as you use `pop()` to read the final value.